# Current/Voltage phase shift issue with low/high capacitor capacitance

Tags: resonance, phase-shift, falstad

How to make voltage/current 90 degree phase shift properly?

In my PWM->sine "converter" the current/voltage phase is shifted 90 degree only with low value capacitor (10 uF), but no shift with higher (>10 uF) the current/voltage phase.
I use Falstad simulation for design circuit before implementation.

I want to drive induction motor with PWM from microcontroller, and for it I need 90 degree current shifting between two set of coils.

With low value capacitor current/voltage are shifted, but current/voltage are too low:
[image]

With higher value capacitor no current/voltage shift:
[image]

https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcAmaCBsyCclnq2AMzpgAsYSykISphNApgLRhgBQAbiIcd1d7zAB2dFBDIQQhAA5oQ0uAXVlaNgHcBowv0LSF25WwBOm8CO56zo6gjYAbEKWnVkyBU+oGxMeJCz+AwKCsEBZCaGRpISwEQkhiBCxSOiU2AGMaSKtM6T5lKFg4OmCSrFEmcOjIMGRdeO1MdCVC9g0PPJyOyHUQdAwOoR1+bo1Bz35nccNR-mFRSezugAcQBbnVuA76QxNdBXW98VJ80nsLBTdPSy8JH19S0tCYMqJ0aTAcKjB0dEgkEc6XkSEi8AIQWXWY0WPWBHT6WmGxkczmy4Ny6xUcHYJnarncKIxBTghCcQh6dAk63aGPJ2g67VB6UcdMuzJBwyJ9wewVCpDkhCwyDAfkg6CEUhF-xaSIp2VlrOopw0hy8ssZyssVLpNIA9mJbo4-CEdBF9WJCGw9cLxGJjv5wJ5TRBKZ5LeIXLajTQCrkJH7XVbnZ77TBCDUkOEQTbWNw2EA

Thank you in advance.